# How to understand integral of wedge product?

Tags: integration, differential-forms

Taken from Bott and Tu (page 70):

> Let $\sigma$ be the positive generator of $H^{n-1}(S^{n-1})$ and $\psi = \pi^* \sigma$ the corresponding generator of $H^{n-1}(\mathbf R^n - 0)$. [...] Let $d\rho = \rho'(r)\,dr$ be a bump form on $\mathbf R$ with total integral $1$. Then $(d\rho) \wedge \psi$ is a compactly supported form on $\mathbf R^n$ with total integral $1$.

If it's not already obvious, $\pi$ is the projection $\mathbf R^n - 0 \to S^{n-1}$ and $\rho$ is a function of the radius $r$ in $\mathbf R^n$.

Question: How am I to understand the last sentence intuitively?

So far, the picture in my head is for $n = 3$. I imagine $\sigma \in H^2(S^2)$ to be a function that eats a $2$-dimensional subset of $S^2$ and spits out its area. Then $\psi \in H^2(\mathbf R^3)$ is a function that eats a $2$-manifold in $\mathbf R^3$, projects it onto the unit sphere, and spits out its area. I'm not sure how these help me understand what $d\rho \wedge \psi$ is doing, or why it should integrate to $1$.

Comment: Do you understand that $d\rho \wedge \psi$ is a 3-form, i.e. a function that eats a 3-dimensional manifold in ${\bf R}^3$ and spits out a number? And, by the way, $\sigma$ does not spit out area, it spits out area divided by $4\pi$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Isn't the "standard" area form on the unit sphere $x\,dy\,dz - y\,dx\,dz + z\,dx\,dy$?

Comment: My understanding is that if we're taking singular cohomology with $\mathbf Z$ coefficients, then sure, a generator is a cocycle that eats the fundamental class and spits out 1. But if we're doing de Rham cohomology, then "generator" just means "basis" for the $\mathbf R$-vector space $H^2(S^2)$, so any form that eats $S^2$ and doesn't spit out 0 will do. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes, I think I understand that $d\rho \wedge \psi$ eats 3-manifolds and spits out numbers. I just don't know how it decides what number to spit out.

Comment: The number it spits out is its integral over the domain in question. In this case, $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d\rho \wedge \psi$. So, you have to learn how to integrate differential forms.

Comment: Regarding the phrase "the positive generator of $H^{n-1}S^{n-1}$", since the context is missing I cannot know for sure what they meant, but it seems to me that the use of the definite article "the" means that they have one particular generator in mind.

Comment: Current attempt at understanding: $\int_{\mathbf R^3} d\rho \wedge \psi = \int_{\mathbf R^3 - 0} d\rho \wedge \psi$ because $d\rho$ vanishes at the origin. But $\mathbf R^3 - 0$ is the same as $\mathbf R \times S^2$. Since $d\rho$ is constant along $S^2$ and $\psi$ is constant along $\mathbf R$, Fubini tells us that $\int_{\mathbf R \times S^2} d\rho \wedge \psi = \left( \int_{\mathbf R} d\rho \right) \left( \int_{S^2} \psi \right) = 1 \cdot 1 = 1$. Is this correct?

Comment: ${\bf R}^3 - 0$ is not "the same as" ${\bf R} \times S^2$. When you change variables in an integration, you have to use the change of variables formula.